# Add/Delete phone number in whatsapp business account using api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I want to add/delete phone numbers to a WABA account. It can be done through UI but is there any endpoint to do the same ?
I didn't find any in documentation.

Comment: Hi, Have you found any solution? I am also trying to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try this `/deregister` endpoint, it says:

> Deregister Phone removes a previously registered phone. You can always re-register your phone using by repeating the registration process.

https://www.postman.com/meta/workspace/whatsapp-business-platform/request/13382743-8f0c509c-ec45-44fb-bfcc-38417ce88e97?ctx=documentation

also `/register`:

https://www.postman.com/meta/workspace/whatsapp-business-platform/request/13382743-149d8034-dca8-4bce-827e-06244127b4b7?ctx=documentation